# Media query works in devtools, but not on mobile device

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to use a media query like this:

```
.search-results {
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    @media (max-width: 900px) {
       width: 100vw;
       padding-top: 40px;
    }
}
```

to make it look good in mobile, it works in chrome devtools, but the width stays the same in mobile. Here are the screenshots:
[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIUtJ.png)
[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoM3g.png)

The `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>` tag is included in the `<head>`

Comment: Hi, could you show enough code so we can see the problem see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You probably need to use Javascript to actually detect the *actual* dimensions of your mobile device. Then use *these* dimensions in your CSS

Comment: Useful link one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475907/media-query-about-screen-size-instead-of-resolution

Comment: Useful Link 2: https://lessframework.com/

Comment: @Martin viewportsizer.com said my phone width is 393px and previously there was no such problem

Comment: Can you pls put a codepen link with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @media rule should be outside of the class selector.

```
.search-results {
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .search-results {
       width: 100vw;
       padding-top: 40px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yay thanks!! Weird that it even worked in desktop browser.

Comment: I believe Chrome is rolling out what it calls 'nesting style rules' - which is their take on replicating some of the behavior available in CSS preprocessors such as Less and Sass. This would explain why it worked for you in desktop. https://developer.chrome.com/articles/css-nesting/